# Intel PROSet/Wireless services on startup

Tags: windows-7, wireless-networking, boot

I'm trying to figure out what services I don't need on startup because I don't use most of these programs. 
I remember about a year ago I went to the intel website and did one of those driver update checks and it had me install a bunch of these Intel PROSet/Wireless programs. My computer worked completely fine without them and I just installed them because I want to be up to date. But the problem is that I don't understand why I need them to be running all the time if I never needed them running in the past.
I need help figuring out which services I can un-tick from running on startup. 
I took a screenshot and put a red box around the ones I'm wondering if I can un-tick:

[image]

It says that all of them are running except for the Intel(R) Management & Security Application User Notification Service.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should be able to un-tick all of them. I have to admit that initially I was going to give a shortlist of 6 which you could un-tick (numbers 1, 2, 3, 5, 6 & 7) but I reasoned that wifi drivers tend to be kernel mode drivers in the form of .sys files which you would find somewhere else other than in your screen snip above. Services, like the ones you highlighted, are user mode processes in the form of .exe files and so I think they exist to provide some kind of added value in addition to what you get from the wifi driver. So even if you disable the services you should be able to retain what is offered to you by the wifi driver.

You're probably wanting to know a bit more about what you're un-ticking but you'll get a good description from services.exe. Just looking at the names of the services ('Bluetooth', 'Event Log', etc.) I can hazard a guess that they merely provide additional functionality on top of what you get from the driver.

The only ones I'm not a 100% sure on is the fourth (Registry service) and the eighth one (WiMax service) but even if you encounter any issue disabling those two you should still be able to renable them from services.exe.